# Perform database query without UI hiccups

Tags: android, database, user-interface

I have a simple two-fragment layout with SlidingPaneLayout (from the new revision of v4 support library). Basically when I select an item from the left fragment, the right fragment slides on top of it, and meanwhile loads some data from the database. The problem is that it looks choppy because of the database query. I use Loaders to access the database and the UI draw is done in a different task than the database requests... How should I solve this issue? Should I set a listener for the sliding animation, and when it's done, do the database request?

Comment: If you're using `Loader`s properly, it won't cause any UI hiccups as they are meant specifically to avoid that. If you can post your code here, maybe we can figure out what's going on...

Comment: One thing I should have probably mentioned is that I use a typeface created from an asset. Does that have any effect on the performance of my listView? (I use it as the typeface of the list rows)

Comment: How are you doing it? Are you creating a new Typeface for each listview item?

Comment: No, I load the typeface in the onActivityCreated function and set the typeface for the rows individually with a ViewBinder. But it turned out that it wasn't the problem, since commenting out the typeface-related lines didn't really solve the problem.

Comment: Could you please add your code? That'll be much more helpful in nailing the issue...

Comment: Which parts of my code should I add?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30353/discussion-between-vinay-s-shenoy-and-csongor-kiss)